CloudConvert reports "Incomplete download" error
I try to use CloudConvert to convert some files. However, for some file types, it will always report "Incomplete download" error when importing the source file, as below:
Payload
{
    "operation": "import/url",
    "url": "https://www.repairrar.com/wp-content/plugins/file-converter/temp/test-1724581969.csv"
}

Incomplete download: Downloaded 7 bytes but Content-Length header is 11 bytes

However, I use https://www.uptrends.com/tools/http-response-header-check to check the import URL: https://www.repairrar.com/wp-content/plugins/file-converter/temp/test-1724581969.csv
And the response shows the content-length is 7, not 11, as below:
RESPONSE HEADERS
Server  nginx/1.26.1
Date    Sun, 25 Aug 2024 10:39:14 GMT
Content-Type    text/csv
Content-Length  7
Connection  keep-alive
Last-Modified   Sun, 25 Aug 2024 10:32:49 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Robots-Tag    noindex, nofollow
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=63072000
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Referrer-Policy no-referrer, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
X-Proxy-Cache   DISABLED

So why CloudConvert will report such an error? I encounter the same issue with .RAR files. But other file types are OK.
I try to contact CloudConvert but get no responses at all.
